# For loop causing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when setting value of array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on adding a random number to an array. I start by creating an array of variable size

```
    String diceAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "How Many Die Would You Like To Roll Today?");
    return x = Integer.parseInt(diceAmount);

    int[] diceRoll = new int[x];
```

I then try and fill the array with random numbers:

```
    int z = ran.nextInt(5) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
                diceRoll[x] = z;
```

However whenever I pick a number of dice and then run my actionEvent it returns a OutOfBoundsArrayException. I have tried switching around everything trying new variables and such, any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: try printing out the size of the diceroll array, if it's 0 obviously you're going out of bounds. If that's fine, more code is probably required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remeber your array length is x, so if I had an array of size 10 and used array[10] it would through an index out of bounds because the array starts at 0 not 1. So in your loop you should be using i as your index and going between 0 and x-1

Change

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
            diceRoll[x] = z;
```

to

```
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            diceRoll[i] = z;
```

also note that you are adding the same random number to every index of the array, so if the random number was 3 then your whole diceRoll array would be filled with 3s. You should remove variable Z and set each value of your array to a new random number

```
diceRoll[i] = z;
```

to

```
diceRoll[i] = ran.nextInt(5) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, works perfectly. One more question, I am then adding the array elements together in an actionEvent and outputting the sum. However when I roll the dice again it adds the new amount to the old amount. How can I reset the values in the array to be assigned again?

Comment: I doubt the problem is your array saving the values, but rather your sum not reseting before you add up the new total. Make sure you set the sum to 0 before you add the array values back up.

Comment: alight awesome, thank you so much. I realized I needed to reset sum to O in the other actionEvent. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
  diceRoll[x] = z;
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  diceRoll[i] = z;
```

Comment: And `diceRoll[x]` should be `diceRoll[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe worth mentioning (on top of Louis' answer):

Say

- `x = 6`
- `i starts on 0`
- `length of diceRoll = 6`, since `int[] diceRoll = new int[x]`

`i <= x` would result in 7 loops `0..1..2..3..4..5..6` though `diceRoll` can't handle 7 values. `diceRoll` has the following keys available `0..1..2..3..4..5`. Setting `diceRoll[6]` would thus result in an `OutOfBoundsArrayException`.

`i < x` would result in 6 loops `0..1..2..3..4..5`, same as the available keys on `diceRoll`. This wouldn't cause an `OutOfBoundsArrayException` because all values of `i` during the loop are 'available' in `diceRoll`.

Comment: indeed, common newbie mistake